# Removing .php extension in URLs except sub directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hello I used below code to remove extension .php from url  in .htaccess
index.php -------- index and it worked fine.

Please assist me to stop this from removing the .php extension in sub directories eg:  `www.example.com/cp/index`  instead of:  `www.example.com/cp/index.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [NC,L,QSA,R=301]
```

The following did not work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/?
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1.php [L]
```

Can I the exception directory  one specific  call cp

Comment: please rephrase this sentance " Can I the exception directory  one specific  call cp", as it is impossible to understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#####exclude /cp folder####
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cp
#################
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /((?!cp)[^.]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [NC,L,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /cp/login was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.


i think  we need dont remove .php in cp sub directories 

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [NC,L,QSA,R=301]

Comment: pls see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39541836/customized-htassess-url
@starkeen