# Customized .htaccess url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this code in below work fine

### old code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#####exclude /cp folder####
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /((?!cp)[^.]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [NC,L,QSA,R=301]


RewriteRule ^singer/(.*)$ singer.php?s=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^album/(.*)$ album.php?a=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^lyric/(.*)$ lyric.php?l=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^singers/(.*)$ singers.php?p=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

---

```
RewriteRule ^album/(.*)$ album.php?a=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

http://example.com/album.php?a=11      http://example.com/album/11

i want edit it to  GET variables with PHP  exam

http://example.com/album/year/2016 http://example.com/album.php?y=2016

so i right this code

```
RewriteRule ^album/([0-9]+)$ album.php?a=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^album/year/([0-9]+)$ album.php?y=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

i see Internal Server Error
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. on request

http://example.com/album/year/2016  or http://example.com/album/20

put work fine in all page

new code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#####exclude /cp folder####
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cp
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /((?!cp)[^.]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [NC,L,QSA,R=301]

RewriteRule ^singer/(.*)$ singer.php?s=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^album/([0-9]+)$ album.php?a=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^album/year/([0-9]+)$ album.php?y=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^lyric/(.*)$ lyric.php?l=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^singers/(.*)$ singers.php?p=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

now i comment this line 7   #`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`  my code work fine put page without get variables   stop work

ex
http://example.com/singers  http://example.com/about

Comment: @starkeen pls help me

Comment: when do you get the 500 error? and did you check your apache error_log for specific reason?

Comment: 41.69.253.80 - - [17/Sep/2016:05:10:29 +0200] "GET /album/200 HTTP/1.1" 500 669 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
Unfortunately Unhelpful  error_log

Comment: That s not error log, thats the access log.  try again.

Comment: @PanamaJack pls tel me where i can found log file i used centos 6.8  with cpanel apatch  2.4

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3

where i put this line LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3

Comment: I don't use servers with cpanel, cpanel changes the default location for apache error log. You'll have to check cpanel docs for location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try change  `^(.*)$ $1.php`  to

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^(.*[^0-9])$ $1.php
```